File allocations methods
I was solving a problem that was asking me to use the 3 different types of allocations, contiguous, linked list and index allocations. I then got a list of different files with different sizes and was told the block size is 512 Bytes.
My question is lets say I use contiguous allocation for a file of size 12 Bytes, this means that I use one block but 500 bytes of it is unused, if I get another file of size X. Do I need to go to a new block or do I have to first make use of the remaning 500 byes, of course assuming there is a contiguous free blocks large enough to fit in X?
Regardless if the answer is yes or no on the first question, what about the other allocation methods? If I only use a small part of the block, can't a new file use that or does it need its own unique blocks?
Thanks beforehand

Practically any operating system will reserve whole blocks, in your case one 512 byte block for 12 bytes
Otherwise for example adding 10 bytes to the file would be very hard.
Imagine you have two files of 256 and 255 bytes in one block, then you increase the first file by two bytes so both files don’t fit anymore. You now have to move a totally unrelated file.
